# How to map objects in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not sure if the title makes sense, but you can have a look at the example below. Considering I have a 2-column table in Excel like this:

```
Fruit   |   Amount
Apple   |     2
Grape   |     4
Orange  |     3
```

Now I want to have this row:

```
Apple | Apple | Grape | Grape | Grape | Grape | Orange | Orange | Orange
```

that when I change the number from "Amount" column in the table, the row changes accordingly as well. For example, if I now have 5 Grapes, it would become:

```
Apple | Apple | Grape | Grape | Grape | Grape | Grape | Orange | Orange | Orange
```

Is it possible to do in Excel? I am fairly new with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with a combination of

- `REPT` - to generate the repated copies of the words
- `CONCAT` - to join those repitions together
- `FILTERXML` - to split the list into cells
- `TRANSPOSE` - to return a row rather than a column

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<a>"&CONCAT("<b>"&REPT(B5:B7&"</b><b>",C5:C7-1)&B5:B7&"</b>")&"</a>","//b"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I am looking for. May I ask what all those <a>, <b>, </b> are? Or are they just for formating?

Comment: They are the engine that makes `FILTERXML` work.  [A good read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697)

Answer (score 4):

Currently in BETA, but if available through insider's plan, try to use `SCAN()`:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(1,SUM(B2:B4)),SCAN(0,B2:B4,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),A2:A4,,1)
```

---

Let me try and explain the steps:

- The [SCAN()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/scan-function-d58dfd11-9969-4439-b2dc-e7062724de29) functionality can be used to create a running total. A starting value of 0 will continue to grow through recursive `LAMBDA()` functionality. In the current example this will return `{2,6,9}`.
- Now the idea is to find approximate matches using [XLOOKUP()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929). The input for this function is an array created through [SEQUENCE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90) where the amount of columns will equal the `SUM()` of all amounts. Thus; `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` in this case. Using the 5th parameter we can return the position of the exact *or* nearest higher value in the lookup array we found using `SCAN()`. The result: `{1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3}`.
- The next and last step is also done in `XLOOKUP()` where we used `A2:A4` inside the 2nd parameter to return elements from the previous found numeric indices. Obviously the result will then be `{"Apple","Apple","Grape","Grape","Grape","Grape","Orange","Orange","Orange"}` .

---

I tried to visualize the above in a process that may help a little.

[image]

---

And as your amount change, so does the output as required:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function to do a text multiple. You can then stack up the results.

```
Function TextMultiplier(MyText As String, MyMultiple As Integer)

Dim Output As String

For a = 1 To MyMultiple
    Output = Output + MyText + " "
Next a

TextMultiplier = Trim(Output)

End Function
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: They tagged their question with [tag:excel-formula], so I'd assume that they're looking for a formula, not a VBA solution.

Comment: You have programmed the already existing `REPT()` Excel function :-)