# How to repeat text in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to ask for your advices. I have a problem with this
[image]
I tried to use REPT in excel but the result show all multiplied word in on cell. How Can I improve it?

I want to result be like

[image]

and sort from Z to A by code. How can I do it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Try the following formula-

```
=DROP(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(A1:A3&"|",B1:B3)),,"|"),-1)
```

[image]

Comment: To sort in descending order, use `=SORT(DROP(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(A1:A3&"|",B1:B3)),,"|"),-1),,-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74571541/9758194) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69803570/9758194) one are *very* similar, if not a duplicate. Maybe the only thing that tells these apart is the fact that you seem to want a "z..a" order (which does not reflect in your desired result btw). I did implement it here below:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=SORT(XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(B1:B3)),SCAN(0,B1:B3,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),A1:A3,,1),,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution - using `MAKEARRAY`:

```vb
=LET(d,A1:B3,
m,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(d),MAX(INDEX(d,,2)),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(c<=INDEX(d,r,2),INDEX(d,r,1),#N/A))),
SORT(TOCOL(m,2),,-1))
```

I added `SORT` at the end as you wrote "sort from Z to A by code"

Comment: `REDUCE()` will more easier with `EXPAND()` function.

Comment: @Harun24hr: sorry, I don't get your point .... can you explain?

Comment: I meant to use `REDUCE()` function like `=DROP(REDUCE("",B1:B3,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,EXPAND(INDEX(A1:A3,ROW(x)),x,,INDEX(A1:A3,ROW(x)))))),1)`